# Pass down a function with same name in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I can passdown `props` with spread operator. ie,

```
<Component x={props.x} y={props.y} />
```

is equal to:

```
<Component {...props} />
```

And we can use it in the component definition with the same name.

My question is how can I pass a function like this? What is the equivalent code for below?

```
<Component handleClick = {this.handleClick} 
   anotherHandleClick = {this.anotherHandleClick}/>
```

**Edit:**

Above line will pass down the function `handleClick` and `anotherHandleClick` to the child. Is there something like `<Component {...Fns} />` so that every function will pass down as props with the same name.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, because you asked it then immediately answered it with the last piece of code.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi he want's something like this 

`let handleClick = this.handleClick; <Component {....{handleClick} } />`

but in one line, which to my knowledge is impossible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes , You can do it like :

**1) First way :**

```
render() {
   const methods = { handleClick : this.handleClick };
   return(
        <Component {...methods} />
   )
}
```

**2) Second way :**

Without using any extra varible `const methods = { handleClick : this.handleClick };`

```
render() {
    return(
        <Component {...this.constructor.prototype} />
        // or
        <Component {...this.__proto__} />
    )
}
```

> NOTE : The second method is not preferable as it gives all the access
>   of class to a child, all means all, constructor, render everything....
>
> I just want to show the ways we can achieve, still if there are lots
>   of functions we can go with second way too, but be careful with that.

---

Here is the working example for both of above, please have a look :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-parent-click-prop